# Geofence Update Interval - Android

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I have a question about *Geofences* in Android, is there any way to set a position update interval when creating *Geofences*? The idea is to build a very responsive *Geofence* application

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I think you'll be pleasantly supprised at the quality of the geofense api